# Matplotlib kiwisolver import problem _cext

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having the followoing error when running my script. I have tried uninstalling matplotlib and reinstalling it and the same for kiwisolver. I'm using python 3.11.2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "c:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\XXXX\XXXX\.venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "c:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\XXXXX\XXXX\.venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 240, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\XXX\Downloads\XXXX\XXXX\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable fixes the problem.

You can download it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution open the windows powershell and installing this:

```
pip install msvc-runtime
```