# Matplotlib installed but not recognized in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, environment

for some reason I can't get Matplotlib to work. I am running python version 3.10 from my Windows cmd prompt. pip, numpy, scipy, matplotlib are all installed and up to date.

Specifically, my code starts by calling

```
from pylab import *
```

However I get the error message that the pylab module cannot be found. This is an identical code I run on different machines but this is the first time I've seen this error on this new PC. I have tried, before this line, to put

```
import matplotlib
```

but it returns the same error (this time saying matplotlib module could not be found). I definitely have numpy, scipy, matplotlib installed. Below is my output verifying matplotlib is installed, followed by me trying to run my code and it saying module matplotlib doesn't exist:

```
C:\PATH>pip show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.7.1
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: c:\users\swidso3\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
Requires: contourpy, cycler, fonttools, kiwisolver, numpy, packaging, pillow, pyparsing, python-dateutil
Required-by: MetPy

C:\PATH>python halo1_rt_v6.6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PATH\halo1_rt_v6.6.py", line 17, in <module>
    from decode_halo import decode_halo
  File "C:\PATH\code\decode_halo.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\PATH\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 240, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Swidso3\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
```

My guess is this is some weird environment issue? But I am only using cmd to run python, not switching environments...?!? And cmd says matplotlib is installed. I'm very confused and tried troubleshooting on stackoverflow but they all say just use pip install or pip upgrade, both of which haven't worked.

Comment: Similar question, with same root-cause error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75900418/matplotlib-kiwisolver-import-problem-cext

Comment: Hi, 
I actually saw that and already tried it. It did not resolve the issue. 
I just tried that command again and no change, the error output message is the same. Any other ideas? I'm convinced it's something wrong with my env or PATH because I am able to run the script just fine via the Spyder GUI terminal, but not from my cmd prompt in Windows...

Comment: Hi, wondering if you have any advice? 
I tried removing pylab import * but then the error still exists once it calls matplotlib. 
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib, same issue. My pip and matplotlib versions are up to date. Not sure what is happening?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't really use matplotlib much myself, I only found that other question by Googling for it.